# Facebook API: Get basic user info

Tags: authentication, facebook, oauth, authorization

I have a Facebook app that displays content without requiring any authorization from the visitor.
I wish to display the visitor a welcome message ("Hello {USER_NAME}"), but without requiring authorization.

I'm using an iframe, but I can switch to fbml for this.

I'm okay with this only working for the canvas page (http://{MY_DOMAIN}.com/{APP_PAGE}) and not for the page inside facebook (http://app.facebook.com/{APP_PAGE}).

How can this be done?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Dorian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely can't do this with iframe. I'm not sure about fbml, but you can give it a shot by using an fb:name tag and seeing if it renders for anonymous users.